# How to realy include a js file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did't found any realy working solution of this issue on Google, so...

There is a module called `vm`, but people say it is very heavy. I need some simple function, like PHP's `include`, which works like the code of an including file inserts right into the place in code you need and then executes.

I tryed to create such function

```
function include(path) {
    eval( fs.readFileSync(path) + "" );
}
```

but it is not as simple... it is better if I'll show you why in example.

Let's say I need to include **file.js** file with content

```
var a = 1;
```

The relative file look like this

```
include("file.js");
console.log(a); // undefined
```

As you already realized `a` is undefined because it is not inherits from a function.

Seems the only way to do that is to type this long creepy code

```
eval( fs.readFileSync("file.js") + "" );
console.log(a); // 1
```

every time with no wrapper function in order to get all the functionality from a file as it is.

Using `require` with `module.exports` for each file is also a bad idea...

Any other solutions?

Comment: Why is using `require` a bad idea?  Isn't that basically what everybody else in the Node world uses?

Comment: because with `require` I have to append each my variable to `module.exports` object

Comment: @artnikpro: Which is a *good* thing. It makes you think in terms of keeping variables close to your chest, only exposing those you **have** to. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Using require with module.exports for each file is also a bad idea...

No, [`require` is](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require) **the** way you do this in NodeJS:

```
var stuff = require("stuff");
// Or
var stuff = require("./stuff"); // If it's within the same directory, part of a package
```

Break your big `vm` into small, maintainable pieces, and *if* they need to be gathered together into one big thing rather than being used directly, have a `vm.js` that does that.

So for example

`stuff.js`:

```
exports.nifty = nifty;
function nifty() {
    console.log("I do nifty stuff");
}
```

`morestuff.js`:

```
// This is to address your variables question
exports.unavoidable = "I'm something that absolutely has to be exposed outside the module.";

exports.spiffy = spiffy;
function spiffy() {
    console.log("I do spiffy stuff");
}
```

`vm.js`:

```
var stuff     = require("./stuff"),
    morestuff = require("./morestuff");

exports.cool = cool;
function cool() {
    console.log("I do cool stuff, using the nifty function and the spiffy function");
    stuff.nifty();
    morestuff.spiffy();
    console.log("I also use this from morestuff: " + morestuff.unavoidable);
}
```

`app.js` (the app using `vm`):

```
var vm = require("./vm");

vm.cool();
```

Output:

```
I do cool stuff, using the nifty function and the spiffy function
I do nifty stuff
I do spiffy stuff
I also use this from morestuff: I'm something that absolutely has to be exposed outside the module.
```

Comment: replace 'stuff.js' with 'stuff' to set a better example?

Comment: so how do I get `a` variable this way? Do I have to append it to `module.exports` object (and each other variable in the file)?

Comment: @artnikpro: Variables should be contained (restricted) as much as possible. So each bit (`stuff`, in the above) would have variables it used to provide the functionality it exposes. If you need to make a variable available outside of `stuff`, yes, put it on `exports`, and use it directly from there inside `stuff` (so you aren't getting out of sync). But again, best to keep things contained whenever possible.

Comment: Well, it is pretty strange way for me. I am new in node.js, usually developed in PHP and client-side JS, so I think I will need some time to use to it. Thanks!

Comment: @artnikpro: You're welcome! It's not so much a NodeJS thing, it's a modularity thing -- which NodeJS actively encourages. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do breaks modularity and goes against Node.js best practices.

Lets say you have this module (sync-read.js):

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  a: fs.readFileSync('./a.json'),
  b: fs.readFileSync('./b.json'),
  c: fs.readFileSync('./c.json')
}
```

When you call the module the first time ...

```
var data = require('./sync-read');
```

... it will be cached and you wont read those files from disk again. With your approach you'll be reading from disk on every `include` call. No bueno.

You don't need to append each of your vars to `module.exports` (as in comment above):

```
var constants = {
  lebowski: 'Jeff Bridges',
  neo: 'Keanu Reeves',
  bourne: 'Matt Damon'
};

function theDude() { return constants.lebowski; };
function theOne() { return constants.neo; };
function theOnly() { return constants.bourne; };

module.exports = {
  names: constants,
  theDude : theDude,
  theOne : theOne
  // bourne is not exposed
}
```

Then:

```
var characters = require('./characters');

console.log(characters.names);

characters.theDude();
characters.theOne();
```